# How to install Tix on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tix

I have been trying to install `Tix` to create a GUI in Python, and I couldn't make it.

My computer characteristics are:

- Macbook Pro
- Processor: Intel 2.4GHz intel core i5
- Architecture: 64-bits

And Python version is: `Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)|`

I am using Aptana Studio 3.

I have been trying using Macports and it has been impossible. Do you know a way you have succeeded with?

Comment: I recommend against using Tix. It hasn't seen active development since 2008, and there are good alternatives for much of what is in tix. Just about everything you need to do with tix you can do with standard Tkinter and ttk widgets.

Comment: Dear @BryanOakley, thanks for your prompt response. Actually I wanted to used Tix since It's possible to create forms with relational data in a Tkinter form. However, now you say It's obsolete, so, I will appreciate it your advise concerning to this or an example what to follow to create my gui (form with relational data). I have to tell you that I think sqlite is not an option since the data is quite small. Hope you can help me with my problem!. Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I went through this today. It was painful. Can you tell me which error you received so I can make sure and recapitulate it? It requires some special flags in your configure script, but without your error I can't remember what they are.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [small guide](https://gist.github.com/leo-labs/012ab6f5153b5e9b8c13). Maybe this will help others:

*Notes: The specified version numbers are important, since Tix 8.4 does not work with Tcl/Tkl 8.6.x*

- Install [xQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
- Download [Tcl 8.5 and Tk 8.5](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html)
- Download [Tix 8.4](http://tixlibrary.sourceforge.net/)
- Copy into directory structure `./src/Tix8.4.x`, `/src/Tcl8.5.x`, `/src/Tk8.5.x`
- Compile Tcl:

  ```
  cd ./src/Tcl8.5.x
  ./configure --enable-shared
  make
  ```
- Compile Tk:

  ```
  cd ./src/Tk8.5.x
  ./configure --enable-shared
  make
  ```
- Tix:

  ```
  cd ./src/Tix8.4.x
  ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11/lib" --enable-shared
  make
  make install
  ```
- Set Tix Library path (e.g. in your .bashrc/.zshrc) to let python find the tix library:
  `export TIX_LIBRARY="/usr/local/lib/Tix8.4.x"` (adjust version number)
- You are done!